# Accessing useState value from jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In a class based component I can easily access state by doing:

```
const control = shallow(<Test />);
control.state()
```

For a hooks based component like the one below, how can I access `count` from my test?

```
const Test = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count</button>
            <div>{count}</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: The state is an internal implementation detail of the component. Test the *behaviour*, the value rendered into the DOM.

Comment: You cannot implicitly test the `useState` value

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible, and it shouldn't be, given that the state is an implementation detail. If you rename the state to `myCount`, the component still works, but the test would fail.

#### Alternative 1: Test the DOM

However, since you render the count, you can simply expect that the correct count is rendered.

Example using `react-testing-library`:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library'

const rendered = render(<Test />)
rendered.getByText(0) // Test that 0 is present in the DOM
fireEvent.click(rendered.getByText('Count'))
rendered.getByText(0) // Test that 1 is present in the DOM
```

#### Alternative 2: Extract the state logic in a reducer, and test the reducer

If you really want to test the state updates in isolation, you can [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), and test the reducer easily with `jest`, since it is a pure JavaScript function.